# Trying to download foreign aps

Tags: google-play-store, gps, ip-address

I've been trying to customize my android. Found a cool set of buttons but one problem. The app store says it is "not available in (my) country" I have tried spoofing the GPS but that did not work. Does anyone have an idea about how to spoof cell towers or IP addresses to get around the lock out?

I  have surfed through the "duplicate" questions and tried all of those suggestions to no avail.  Best I can tell the problem is the cell towers. But there should still be a way to hack this.

Comment: Have you tried disabling your mobile network (maybe even taking out the SIM) and using Wifi only, possibly over a VPN?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't do that easily; GPS spoofing, VPN and Market Enabler won't work. I believe the only way is to register a valid foreign credit card of that country on Google Wallet, then try to buy an app, as already answered by Google support itself on one of the duplicates. Have you tried that? Alternatively, find the APK from somewhere and install it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Download an app from the play store called Psiphon:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.psiphon3&hl=en_GB

It allows you to create a vpn, connect to the US one.

If it still doesn't work, you can try several other steps:

1. Changing the locale of your device
2. Turn off location all together (easier than GPS spoofing)
3. Change your home address on google

Comment: Tried the other three. How do yo change the google home address?

Comment: Go to your google account settings.

Comment: I have tried all three and to no avail. Can't figure it out.